# How do i set the state from one API call and use the data for URL in next API call?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I need the data from API call 1 to add to the URL of API call 2. The data from API 2 will go into the URL for API 3. I am setting the state on each Axios request and it is not working. Returning undefined

```
componentDidMount() {
  // Get the IP adress of user
  axios
    .get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        ip: res.data.ip
      });
      console.log(`IP : ${this.state.ip}`);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  // GET the coordinates of a location based on IP adress
  axios
    .get(
      'https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY&ipAddress=24.8.227.87'
    )
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: res.data.location.lat,
        longitude: res.data.location.lng
      });
      console.log(
        `Latitude: ${this.state.latitude}. Longitude: ${this.state.longitude}`
      );
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  // Make the API call on page load
  axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=39.6924553&lon=-105.0256318`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'user-key': 'USER_KEY'
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      const restaurantsNearMe = res.data.nearby_restaurants;

      this.setState({
        restaurants: restaurantsNearMe
      });

      // Pick out a random retaurant from what the API returns
      var randomRestaurant =
        restaurantsNearMe[
          Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantsNearMe.length)
        ];

      // Select only the data that you want
      var finalResult = {
        name: randomRestaurant.restaurant.name,
        id: randomRestaurant.restaurant.id,
        rating: randomRestaurant.restaurant.user_rating.aggregate_rating,
        ratingColor: randomRestaurant.restaurant.user_rating.rating_color,
        address: randomRestaurant.restaurant.location.address,
        delivery: randomRestaurant.restaurant.is_delivering_now,
        typeOfFood: randomRestaurant.restaurant.cuisines
      };

      this.setState({
        restaurant: finalResult
      });
      console.log(this.state.restaurant);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Check out promise chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining. It's the feature you're looking for, and the MDN article explains why certain slices of state are undefined when it seems like they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `callback` in `setState`, and in that `callback` you need to call your second `API` and so on. Check [this](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296?gi=17ebf42cd3eb).

This is what you want,

```
axios
    .get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            ip: res.data.ip
        }, () => {
            // GET the coordinates of a location based on IP adress
            axios
                .get(
                    'https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY&ipAddress=24.8.227.87'
                )
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        latitude: res.data.location.lat,
                        longitude: res.data.location.lng
                    }, () => {
                        // Make the API call on page load
                        axios({
                                method: 'get',
                                url: `https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=39.6924553&lon=-105.0256318`,
                                headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    Accept: 'application/json',
                                    'user-key': 'USER_KEY'
                                }
                            })
                            .then(res => {
                                const restaurantsNearMe = res.data.nearby_restaurants;

                                this.setState({
                                    restaurants: restaurantsNearMe
                                });

                                // Pick out a random retaurant from what the API returns
                                var randomRestaurant =
                                    restaurantsNearMe[
                                        Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantsNearMe.length)
                                    ];

                                // Select only the data that you want
                                var finalResult = {
                                    name: randomRestaurant.restaurant.name,
                                    id: randomRestaurant.restaurant.id,
                                    rating: randomRestaurant.restaurant.user_rating.aggregate_rating,
                                    ratingColor: randomRestaurant.restaurant.user_rating.rating_color,
                                    address: randomRestaurant.restaurant.location.address,
                                    delivery: randomRestaurant.restaurant.is_delivering_now,
                                    typeOfFood: randomRestaurant.restaurant.cuisines
                                };

                                this.setState({
                                    restaurant: finalResult
                                });
                                console.log(this.state.restaurant);
                            })
                            .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    });
                    console.log(
                        `Latitude: ${this.state.latitude}. Longitude: ${this.state.longitude}`
                    );
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));

        });
        console.log(`IP : ${this.state.ip}`);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing to keep in mind, this.setState is not synchronous. React batches multiple set state calls to improve render performance. That's why you might be seeing undefined in the console.log.
setState method takes a callback as second parameter.

`this.setState(newState, callbalck)`

so try to console log in the callback and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how do you call API's but, try something like this:

In `componentDidMount` you can do this:

```js
async componentDidMount(){
  const resApiOne = await callFirstApi();
  this.setState({resApiOne});
  const resApiTwo = await callSecondApi(resApiOne);
  this.setState({resApiTwo});
}
```